# How Generate Custom Dictionary Password list

Tags: passwords, dictionary

I want to generate a password list that has 8 characters like this:

Characters are: `Pp|Aa|Ss|Ww|o0|Rr|Dd`

First character only can be `Pp`, second `Aa@`, .... to end.

How can I make this list using crunch or similar scripts?

Comment: Read the documentation or google a tutorial to use crunch, this is not the place to ask for this

Comment: Regex is your friend on this one.

Comment: stackoverflow.com where you question should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a tool that expands regexes, such as [exrex](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex
$ cd exrex
$ python exrex.py '[pP][aA@][sS$][sS$][wW][oO0][rR][dD]'
password
passworD
passwoRd
passwoRD
passwOrd
passwOrD
passwORd
passwORD
passw0rd
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will do exactly what you want it to, but there's a python tool on github called CUPP that generates user passwords based on information fed to it. Depending on the information fed to it, it generates a relatively large wordlist.

The code [here](https://github.com/Mebus/cupp)